# Software center remains unrepaired

Tags: software-center

The last time I had a broken software centre, I managed to fix things through upgrading Linux to a newer version. Regrettably as I have the latest version, this is no longer possible. Yet the same problem persists.
When I run software centre, I am being told it is broken and needs repairs. I click on a button offering me to fix it. It is fixing itself for a while and then this happens:

```
installArchives() failed: Pednastavuji balky...
Pednastavuji balky...
Pednastavuji balky...
Pednastavuji balky...
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 301765 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking wine1.4-i386 (from .../wine1.4-i386_1.4-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.4-i386_1.4-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/wine', which is also in package wine1.5 1.5.5-0ubuntu1~ppa1~oneiric1+pulse17
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wine1.4-i386_1.4-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.4-common:
 wine1.4-common depends on wine1.4 (= 1.4-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package wine1.4 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing wine1.4-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

What do I do?

Comment: How did you install wine?

Comment: From the official repository at http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You are installing (or) upgrading wine from official store and you already have installed via ppa. That is the problem.

Install ppa purge `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

Purge the ppa for wine.

Comment: If software center is not working, I doubt he can install anything.

Comment: I've actually solved the problem by sudo apt-get remove wine1.5 and then following the recommended procedures meticulously. I feel a little embarrassed that the fix was so simple, actually so much that I'd rather just accept the offered answer and run away. It did not work in previous instance of this problem, but now it does. Extremely strange. Since back then the recommended procedures did not work, I suspect that considering the Ubuntu upgrade solved it previously, the solution was still dependent on upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: *12.04 is the actual version. Simply the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Wine 1.5 is old. There are much more recent stable versions both in Canonical's offical repositories (1.6) and in the Wine HQ PPA (1.8). You should therefore remove the current Wine package:

```
sudo apt-get remove wine1.5\*
```

This will likely require the removal of some packages, that depend on Wine. Confirm the safety question, if they look to be related to Wine (by name). Then continue the installation according to [the instructions from your comment](//wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu#Installing_WineHQ_packages):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

Comment: The question is from 2012....

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Yeah, I only noticed that after I wrote my answer. But at this point I thought, "meh, whatever, maybe someone reading is will find it useful."